# System of two polynomial equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I am stuck at solving these equations and any help would be appreciated. I don't really care about how the solution would look like as I will be using a program to solve it:

$x_1= (1-2x_1-3x_2)^{6.6}$

$x_2= (1-2x_1-3x_2)^{6.2}$

Edit: I tried dividing the two equations, but couldn't make it work. Also I could try having the first equation in root of $6.6$ on both sides. Then I can easily find $x_2$ , however when I plug it in the second equation it just gets uglier and uglier.

Comment: If you are using a program to solve it then what exactly do you need help with?

Comment: I mean I am writing the program, but I can't just have unknowns on one side of the equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $1-2x_1-3x_2=t^5$. Then the two equations become

$$x_1=t^{33}, x_2=t^{32}.$$

This reduces your task to solving the polynomial equation
$$t^5=1-2t^{33}-3t^{32}$$
i.e.
$$2t^{33}+3t^{32}+t^5-1=0.$$

Comment: Do you know of any ways to find all of the roots of that polynomial efficiently @S.Dolan?

Comment: There are many machine programs for solving polynomial equations efficiently. If I had to do it with the help of a pocket calculator I guess I would use interval bisection as an easy to understand method.